# Como faço para passar a sessão do contexto A para o contexto B dentro do Tomcat 05

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlet

Tento duas aplicações feitas em ***Java*** usando ***Tomcat 6*** e estão em **contextos diferentes** mas **uma interage com a outra**, 
por estarem integrados, preciso que um possa passar sua sessão para o outro contexto,
ou que o contextoA possa setar os valores no contextoB.

Ex:

*ContextoA.* `sessao.setAttribute("user", u);`

*ContectoB.* `User u = (User)sessao.getAttribute("user");`

Answer (score 4):

Este é um tópico um pouco extenso, mas basicamente você precisa configurar a replicação de sessão conforme descrito na [documentação do Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).

O passo mais básico, segundo a documentação, é adicionar a configuração abaixo no `server.xml`, dentro da tag `<Engine>` ou `<Host>`:

```xml
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
```

No entanto, a configuração acima replica os valores para todos os nós do *cluster* de Tomcats.

Para um ajuste mais fino é importante ler a documentação em detalhes.

Comment: OK muito obrigado, brilhante a ideia de replicar, vou dar uma boa lida na Doc, já tava pensando em fazer "Gambi" rsrs. Vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Honestamente eu iria por uma abordagem mais programática, pois a configuração de cluster pode influenciar em muita coisa a infra.

Utilize a abordagem de gerar um token e salve-o no banco. Desse modo ambos projetos acessariam o Token e veria se ainda está válido.